# not only A but B structure

Tags: sentence-construction, structure

I'm wondering whether "not only" can be placed in front of a verb, when the objects in a sentence share the same verb.

> Sam plays not only the piano, but the violin.

> Sam **not only** plays the piano, but the violin.

> Sam knows not only how to get there, but when to come back.

> Sam **not only** knows how to get there, but when to come back.

Comment: When you use **not only** with nouns, noun clauses and noun phrases, you normally say **but also**. Your first sentence should therefore end "but **also** the violin**. It's optional in the second sentence  because **when to come back** is a relative clause, not a noun.

Comment: I agree with JavaLatte. I thought you need "but the violin too" or "but also the violin".